# What is the maximum input value for function uint256 parameter?

Tags: solidity

folks!

I am new to Solidity, and have a question, that may sound silly, but I can't really figure it out. So, I have this simple function:

```
function uintTest(uint256 n) returns (uint256) {
        return n;
    }
```

I thought, the max value for uint256 is 2**256, however, the function does not work for input numbers that have more than 16 digits, and in Remix, throws an "assertion failed" error. I can't understand why.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The max value is 2^256-1. The assertion you're hitting is in Remix. The full error message is:

> Error encoding arguments: Error: Assertion failed

The issue is that Remix uses JSON to parse the argument list, and JavaScript only supports numbers up to 2^53-1. The reason you're seeing the issue where you do in terms of number of 9s is because

```
999999999999999 < 2**53-1 < 9999999999999999
```

To fix the issue, just put double quotes around the number you're passing in. It's safe to just always wrap your numbers in quotes to avoid such precision issues.

EDIT:

In version `^0.8.0` of solidity, you can get the max value like so:

```js
function getMaxUint() public pure returns(uint256){
        unchecked{
            return uint256(0) - 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

The reason 2^256 is not the correct number is that one of the possible values needs to be reserved for the zero value.

Imagine a 2 bit number - the max value is not 2^2 (= four) but rather 2^2-1 (= three). Brute forcing it:

00 = zero
01 = one
10 = two
11 = three

There are no more possible combinations of 2 bits - so there's no way to express the number four.