# What is the maximum value an int and uint can store

Tags: solidity, remix, evm

I need to understand a couple of things:

1. What is the maximum value an int and uint can store?
2. Are the maximum values stored in int and uint the same?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- An `uint` is short for `uint256`, so it can store 2^256 values - because it's unsigned the maximum value is 2^256-1 (zero needs one space). [What is the maximum input value for function uint256 parameter?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39321/what-is-the-maximum-input-value-for-function-uint256-parameter)
- An `int` is short for `int256` and it can store the same amount of values - because it's signed the maximum (positive) value is 2^256 / 2 - 1.

So the maximum values of `uint` and `int` are not the same. They have the same amount of values but `int` needs to store values also for negative numbers.

You can find more details at: [Max/min values of standard data types](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27813/max-min-values-of-standard-data-types)

Comment: 2^256/2 - 1 = 2^255 -1

Answer (score 11):

It works as same as other programming languages.

`uint` can store `2^256-1` numbers.

`int` store half of it. e.g. `2^256/2-1` numbers.

```
Int8 — [-128 : 127]
Int16 — [-32768 : 32767]
Int32 — [-2147483648 : 2147483647]
Int64 — [-9223372036854775808 : 9223372036854775807]
Int128 — [-170141183460469231731687303715884105728 : 170141183460469231731687303715884105727]
Int256 — [-57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819968 : 57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819967]


UInt8 — [0 : 255]
UInt16 — [0 : 65535]
UInt32 — [0 : 4294967295]
UInt64 — [0 : 18446744073709551615]
UInt128 — [0 : 340282366920938463463374607431768211455]
UInt256 — [0 : 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935]
```

Answer (score 0):

***Don’t trust verify***

Here is how much uint8 can store in decimals:
2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2
or
**2^256**

```
2^7 * 1 + 2^6 * 1 + 2^5 * 1 + 2^4 * 1 + 2^3 * 1 + 2^2 * 1 + 2^1 * 1 + 2^0 * 1 
= 2^8 - 1
= 255
```

By the same token, uint256 can store in decimals:

```
2^256 - 1
= 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935
```

Answer (score 0):

Scientific notation of the max value of uint256, since it is sometimes easier to reason with:

Raw Value
`115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935`

Scientific Notation:
`1.15792089237320006134268624010 × 10^77`
Or
`1.15792089237320006134268624010e+77`